# Java - Synchronizing and Starting Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I was wondering, if I make a method `synchronized` and then start a `Thread` in this method when will other `Thread`s be able to use the method?

```
synchronized void someMethod() {
    //Do stuff.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public  void run() {
            //Do more stuff.
        }
    }).start();
}
```

That is, will other `Thread`s be able to access `someMethod` when the `Thread` calling `someMethod`exits it or will the newly created `Thread`have to finish as well?

Comment: The newly created thread doesn't have any different/special access than anything else. The only difference is that the new thread must see any changes you make in the synchronized block before the thread is started, even though there is no guarantee for any other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Thread calling someMethod exits it, it won't wait for new Thread to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the monitor on object instance to which `someMethod()` belongs is released. This should be after the call to `Thread.start()` in your code. There is no magic here, standard rules for `synchronized` apply.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized method means only one thread is able to access any of the method execution at once. That's including declaring and performing a new instance, also new thread instance as in your example:

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public  void run() {
            //Do more stuff.
        }
    }).start();
```

The thread which is next to be triggered would declare a new and different instance, and due the fact you haven't stored the former declared threads anywhere, it wouldn't be accessable.

It could be accessed with some modifications:

```
synchronized void someMethod(int id, HashMap threadsMap) {
    //Do stuff.
    threadsMap.set(id, new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public  void run() {
            //Do more stuff.
        }
    }));
threadsMap.get(id).start();
}
```

This would allow you to access each thread by its id